# how to handle back button action in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use navigation drawer ,when I select a specific fragment i replace the current fragment ,when i press back button the app will exit,is there any way to go the previous fragment?

```
Feedback fragment = new Feedback();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_home, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
    new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            // Update your UI here.
        }
    });
```

Maybe this helps? Source: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are already adding your fragment transactions to the back stack, but by default, the back button just goes to any previous Activity, not fragment.

You need to override onBackPressed to specify that you want to go through your fragment backstack, you can do this by adding the following in your activity. You check if there is anything in your back stack, and if there is you 'pop' the back stack, if there is nothing in the back stack, the back button just does it's normal thing:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```